# Binomial distribution conditional on previous sampling

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, compound-distributions

When using a Binomial distribution, the bulk of literature assumes that the probability of success $p$ is known, or deterministic.

I would like to get the distribution for a Binomial RV with unknown probability of success $p$, conditional on previous sampling, e.g. with $g$ successes from $M$ trials.

Using Bayes rule, one can use the sampling density to calculate the posterior distribution but has to assume a prior, e.g. a Beta distribution in this example: https://bayesball.github.io/BOOK/proportion.html.

Is Bayes rule (and making an assumption for a prior) the best way to go or should I just use the definition of the compound probability distribution to find it, i.e., $p_H(x) = \int\limits p_F(x|p)\,p_G(p) \operatorname{d}\!p$ ?

Comment: afaik, the way you have phrased your question is essentially bayesian, so you can only follow bayesian approach.  Frequentist alternative would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20a%20binomial%20proportion,failure%20experiments%20(Bernoulli%20trials).

Comment: @seanv507 Thank you for the quick reply and for the useful info. I'm partially interested in the confidence interval, but mostly want to get a distribution for my analysis.

Comment: There are non-Bayesian solutions too---look into predictive distributions